# How to draw a bounding box for a video in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, video-processing, bounding-box

I am interested in knowing how to get a bounding box for detecting blobs in a video. My code involves background subtraction and I am using simple functions:

```
clc
clear all
close all

m=0; n=0;

readerobj = mmreader('dt2.wmv');% dt2 is my sample fixed cam video
vidframes = read(readerobj);

thresh = 15;

bg = read(readerobj,1);
bg_bw = double(rgb2gray(bg));

fr_size = size(vidframes);
width = fr_size(2);
height = fr_size(1);

fg = zeros(height, width);
numFrames=get(readerobj,'NumberofFrames');

for k = 1 : numFrames
    mov(k).cdata = vidframes(:,:,:,k);
    mov(k).colormap = [];
end

movie(mov, 1, readerobj.FrameRate)

a=1; x=[0 0]; p=0; c=0; 

for i = 2:2:numFrames
    fr = read(readerobj,i); 
    fg = zeros(size(fr));
    fr_bw = rgb2gray(fr);       
    fr_diff = abs(double(fr_bw) - double(bg_bw));  
    for j=1:width                 
      for k=1:height
         if ((fr_diff(k,j) > thresh))
             fg(k,j) = 255; %fr_bw(k,j)
         else
             fg(k,j) = 0;
         end
         if (fr_bw(k,j) > bg_bw(k,j))          
           bg_bw(k,j) = bg_bw(k,j) + 1;           
         elseif (fr_bw(k,j) < bg_bw(k,j))
           bg_bw(k,j) = bg_bw(k,j) - 1;     
         end
     end    

    %median filter to remove noise
    L=medfilt2(fg,[5,5]);            

    %removing small parts less than threshold area
    final=bwareaopen(L,4000);               

    %filling the holes
    ifill=imfill(final,'holes');          

    %to know the number of connected objects
    [Ilabel num]=bwlabel(ifill);          

    if (num>=1)
       %region properties of the image
       Iprops=regionprops(Ilabel);            
       %extracting the bounding box properties
       Ibox=[Iprops.BoundingBox]; 
    end
% ????? What do I do next?
end
```

After this, I am looking for code which would continuously draw a bounding box around the blob.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the properties of the `BoundingBox` attribute, there are two fields:

- `ul_corner` - Denotes the upper left corner of the bounding box
- `width` - Denotes the width in each dimension

This is usually a 4 element vector if you are dealing with a single frame.  As such, the first two elements give you the `(x,y)` co-ordinates of the top left corner of the image, while the next two elements give you the width spanned in each dimension.

Supposing that your `BoundingBox` attribute gave you this:

`[1 2 11 14]`

This means that the top left corner is located at `(x,y) = (1,2)` with a width of 11 and a height of 14.  Remember, the `x` co-ordinate spans horizontally from left to right, while the `y` co-ordinate spans vertically from top to bottom.

When you finally obtain this `BoundingBox` attribute, as seen in your `Ibox=[Iprops.BoundingBox];` statement, you can easily superimpose the bounding box onto your frame using the `rectangle` command.  However, keep in mind that the `regionprops` function may return more than one region.  I'm not sure what your overall goal is here, but calling `Iprops.BoundingBox` and encapsulating within brackets will return **ALL** of your bounding box properties as a single vector.  I would suggest reshaping it so that it is an `N x 4` matrix as so:

```
Ibox = reshape(Ibox, 4, length(Iprops))';
```

As such, the i'th row will give you the bounding box for the i'th object in your image.

Using the `fr` variable that you have for the frame, simply do this (assuming that we are delineating the first object in your image):

```
imshow(fr);
hold on;
rectangle('Position', Ibox(1,:), 'EdgeColor', 'r');
```

The `rectangle` command takes in 2 parameters (and optionally more if you want to modify its properties): You can specify if you want a regular rectangle, a rounded rectangle or an ellipse with the first parameter, and the second parameter you give it the dimensions of the rectangle.  Since you want a bounding box, you choose `Position` as the first parameter, and the second parameter is a 4 element vector that denotes the top-left corner of the bounding box, followed by its width and height.

**Conveniently**, this is given by the `BoundingBox` attribute from the `regionprops` structure already, so you just need to substitute `Ibox` in.  You can specify what kind of colour you want for the box.  I chose red (`r`) to make it stand out.

Now if you want to continuously show this for each frame, you simply have to show each image, and call the `rectangle` function each time.

As an example, let's use a built-in MATLAB image and extract the relevant bounding boxes for each of the shapes.

```
BW = imread('text.png');
s  = regionprops(BW);
```

This is a built-in image that contains a bunch of text.  The second MATLAB statement will try to extract all of the relevant bounding boxes for each of the characters.  What `s` will return is an 88 element structure.  Now, let's draw bounding boxes around the first three characters it detects:

```
b1 = s(1).BoundingBox;
b2 = s(2).BoundingBox;
b3 = s(3).BoundingBox;

imshow(BW);
hold on;
rectangle('Position', b1, 'EdgeColor', 'r');
rectangle('Position', b2, 'EdgeColor', 'g');
rectangle('Position', b3, 'EdgeColor', 'c');
```

... and this is what I get.  I have delineated one bounding box as red, one as green, and the other as cyan.

[image]

If you want to automate this for a single frame, do something like this (assuming you do the reshaping I told you about) **and** place this where the question marks are in your code:

```
Ibox = reshape(Ibox, 4, length(Iprops))';
imshow(fr);
hold on;
for k = 1 : size(Ibox, 1)
   rectangle('Position', Ibox(k,:), 'EdgeColor', 'r');
end
```

Hope this helps!